# How does the parentheses in this C code make the result so different?

Tags: c, debugging, code-analysis

The output for this code:

```
#define RECIPROCAL_1(x)     1/(x)
#define RECIPROCAL_2(x)     1/x

main()
{
  float x=8.0, y;
  y = RECIPROCAL_1(x+10.0);
  printf("1/%3.1f = %8.5f\n", x, y);
  y = RECIPROCAL_2(x+10.0);
  printf("1/%3.1f = %8.5f\n", x, y);
}
```

is output =

```
1/8.0 =  0.05556
1/8.0 = 10.12500
```

I can't see how this works though. I appreciate any tips .

Comment: To be extra-safe (always good) you need another pair of parenthesis: `#define RECIPROCAL(x) (1/(x))`

Comment: If you ever want to check your macro evaluations use `gcc -E`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The macro substitutions are expanded like this:

```
y = RECIPROCAL_1(x+10.0)
```

becomes

```
y = 1/(x+10.0);
```

and

```
y = RECIPROCAL_2(x+10.0)
```

becomes

```
y = 1/x+10.0;
```

Because `/` has a higher precedence that `+` the values for `y` are different.

This is an excellent example of why the discerning programmer only reaches for macros when no other solution is viable. And even then, those discerning programmers that feel compelled to use macros, will always use sufficient parenthesise as to make sure such pitfalls are avoided.

Comment: Thank You So Much . So in general, avoid macros and use regular functions?

Comment: Yes, in general,  avoid macros and use regular functions.

Comment: There are many cases where a macro will do what you want and a normal function won't - like if you want to use `RECIPROCAL` in the initializer for a static data table, or if you need it to support several different types. The key thing to take away is that, unless you **really** know what you're doing and have a reason to do otherwise, you should always parenthesize each use of macro arguments inside the macro body.

Comment: @R.. I would concur with that.

Answer (score 2):

Macros just do very basic token substitution, so

```
#define RECIPROCAL_2(x)     1/x
  y = RECIPROCAL_2(x+10.0);
```

is equivalent to

```
  y = 1/x+10.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets expand the macros:

```
y = 1/(x + 10)
```

versus

```
y = 1/x + 10
```

The way operator precedence is done in C, the divisor is performed before the addition is, making #2 (1/x) + 10 instead of 1 / (x + 10). That is why you should always parenthesize your macros.